# loop through text file content line by line and do operation for each line using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to read text file content line by line first line have to read and do some operation and second line do operation and so on using batch file.Please give me some idea.

For example :

first line read and change the directory do operation on the folder.
Second line and change the directory do operation on the folder.
and so on

```
for /F "delims=" %%i in (Text.txt) do (  
  set Z=%%i
  goto BREAK1
)
:BREAK1(
chdir /d %Z%
...do operation...)
```

using above code I was able to do operation for 1st line remaining I am not able to do anything. Please give me some idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not *that* wrong. Use `call` instead of `goto`(which breaks your loop):

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /ad') do (  
  set Z=%%i
  call :BREAK1
)
goto :eof

:BREAK1 (
echo chdir /d %Z%
echo ...do operation...)
```

May I suggest some minor changes to your code?:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%i in (Text.txt) do call :BREAK1 "%%~i" 
goto :eof
:BREAK1 
pushd "%~1"
echo ...do operation in: %cd%
REM insert here the code to be done in every folder
popd
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thanks for solution ,but again only last line of the text file  is changing to the directory. I have text file which contains D:\file1 E:\file2 d:\file3 but only last one is changing to the directory remaining two are not changing.i want to change every directory and do some operation.

Comment: replaced `'dir /b /ad'` with `Text.txt`?

Comment: Ya ,I replaced that but only last line only changing the directory.

Comment: I attached the image what i am getting.You can see that.If u able to solve ,i am very lucky.Please help me

Comment: what do you expect? Being in all three folders at the same time? It leaves the batchfile with the last visited folder (of course). Use `echo ...do operation in %cd%...` to verify, all the folders get visited (as long as they really exist)

Comment: using echo all three lines are showing.But i want to visit,first folder do some operation and then second folder do some operation and the third folder so on...

Comment: all three folders are visited. Wait - do you want to *manually* do something in those folders ("outside" of the script)?

Comment: Not manually ,want to do some work in that folder automatically

Comment: Only in echo it got visited not changed directory.Only final content is visited.I want to visit all three.

Comment: again: they *get* visited.

Comment: It was printed same time three content and finally changed the last content folder directory.And program stopped.

Comment: the prompt you see is the last folder visited by the script after the script ended. The script itself doesn't show you the prompt. `echo %cd%` is the proof, that those folders are indeed visited. `%cd%` is always the current folder. If you still not believe, replace your `echo` command with a simple  `dir` and examine the output.

Comment: Ya sir i am also saying its visited last folder.But i want to work on three folders.We cant able to do that.Sorry for trouble.

Comment: not "also". I claim that  the script changes to *every*  folder (one after the other), but you don't see it, because inside the script there is no prompt shown. Therefore use `echo %cd%` to verify. (Note: I slightly edited the suggested code to work properly with foldernames with spaces)

Comment: I checked sir.Its not happening first line is do operation and which one updated that is showing the current directory.Actually i want to update the CVS folder.In CVS we have so many projects it will take long time.So we want to update particular folder in the project.Which is first one only that is updating remaining are not updating.Please help me sir.

Comment: The code works fine here, Can you confirm, it's working (unchanged, just copy-paste) without any additional code?

Comment: @echo off
for /F "delims=" %%i in (cvs.txt) do call :BREAK1 "%%~i" 
goto :eof
:BREAK1 
pushd "%~1"
echo ...do operation in: %cd%
REM insert here the code to be done in every folder
chdir /d %cd%
set CVSROOT=:pserver:priyangag@10.150.00.00\oj\lk
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CVSNT\cvs.exe"  update -d
popd
goto :eof     This is my code sir.

Comment: Can you tell me sir pushd and popd operation??

Comment: [pushd[(https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) changes the working folder (like `chdir`, but remembers where it came from). [popd](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) jumps back to that remembered folder. Bookmark [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt), it's a great reference of all `cmd` commands.

Comment: Thank you sir.For your support with calm.I am very very thankful to you.

Comment: Using unquoted `%CD%` is dangerous!  Use either `"%CD%"` or use `.` or `.\ ` instead of `%CD%`.   For reasons read at: https://www.thesecurityfactory.be/command-injection-windows.html

Comment: Thank you very much tukan for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to enable:

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
```

Your fixed example (since you were not completely specific I'm using general names too):

```
for /F "delims=" %%i in (Text.txt) do (
    REM to access the variable within the for cycle use !temp_variable!
    SET temp_variable=%%i

    REM Changing directory
    pushd "<directory>"
    <your operation>
    REM returning back
    popd
)
```

Comment: Thanks for support.But for this code also same i am getting.Last line only changing the directory.

Comment: Well that will depend on how you call your operation: You can use either `CALL <exec>` or `START /I /B <exec>`.